# HTML website links not correct

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I have a simple HTML website. I have the following links:

```
  <div id="buttons">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">
    <li><a href="resources.htm">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Make Enquiry</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/"><img border="0" alt="Facebook Link" src="facebook.png">
  </ul>
</div>
```

All of the links work fine. But I have an image under the links:

```
<div class="tel"><img src="images/tel.png"></div>
```

The image is shown correctly, but it acts as a link (to the facebook link that is shown as the last link in the list of links). Do you know why this is happening? as this image is not meant to act as a link.

For example if I make the facebook link the second link (or any link that doesn't make it the last link in the list) then the image doesn't act as a link. But I need the facebook link as the last one.

```
 <div id="buttons">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">
    <li> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/"><img border="0" alt="Facebook Link" src="facebook.png">
    <li><a href="resources.htm">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Make Enquiry</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You did not close the _<a>_ tag preceding the _<img>_ tag, which the browser tries to correct when rendering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the last `<a>` with an `</a>` before the `<img>` otherwise the `img` is part of the link.
Also the first `<li>` is never closed either.

Answer (score 1):

You missed some closing tags.

```
<div id="buttons">
  <ul>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/">
        <img border="0" alt="Facebook Link" src="facebook.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="resources.htm">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Make Enquiry</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```